# Como establecer un fondo de pantalla (background) en angular 8/9

Tags: angular

necesito crear una pagina web de angular, primero quiero saber como puedo setear un fondo de pantalla , he intentando con algunos codigos pero en todos se repiten los 2 mismos problemas

1. el fondo de pantalla no cubre toda la web, tiene unos margenes blancos en los costados (la resolucion del fondo es 2560x1440)
2. Al escribir un texto en el .html de mi programa, estos se escriben ya sea arriba o abajo, depende en donde fueron declarados, antes o despues del background, y quisiera poder sobre este background (lo toma como si fuera una imagen muy grande nada mas)

utilizo angular 8

Comment: Hola Kenny. Tendrías que ver primero si la imagen, de por si tiene fondo blanco, si se le añade un margin o padding, algún estilo que hace que se separe de todo el espacio disponible, hay varias propiedades en css, como fixed, 100vh o 100vw, tambien object fit, sin ver un poco el código es algo complejo dar una respuesta.

Comment: podrias mostrarnos el código que intentaste o tenés?